# Java ActionListener (multiple statements)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

The following is the edited and (extremely basic version) of my codes so you could understand clearly what it is that i am trying to do.  I would like to use:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ }
```

The problem is that i can't edit/ manupulate moves for my chess pieces in the loops under ActionListener but it never functions all statement, it always only functions on one if statement and ignores the others.

```
if(e.getSource()==cSquare[a][b]){  //current source
    if(switcher=="1" && cSquare[a][b].getChessPiece()=="Pawn" ) {}
```

Simple example of ActionListener:

```
 for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
```

....

```
 elements[i][x] = new OriginalElements(i, x, "None");
                elemenents[i][j].setIcon(None);
```

.......

```
        if(elements[i][x].Xpos()==2 && elements[i][x].Ypos()==2){
                        elements[i][x].setIcon(Image);
                        cSquare[i][x].setChessPiece("Image");
                    }
                    elements[i][j].addActionListener(cListener);   //Click do this
                    panel.add(elements[i][jx);
```

My question would be; how could i implement multiple (if, else etc) statements into the ActionListener and make it work on all? rather than only one. I've tried every possibility i know but only seems to work on a single element (e.g. move image from square to another square and replace current square image with 'EmptyImage'.
Thank you for your time.

P.S : ignore the "professonality" of the codes. I changed it to give you a clear understanding;; thanks :)

Comment: `if(switcher=="1" && cSquare[a][b].getChessPiece()=="Pawn" )` See [How Do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You have various errors in your code:

```
if(e.getSource()==cSquare[a][b]){  //current source
    if(switcher=="1" && cSquare[a][b].getChessPiece()=="Pawn" ) {}
```

Strings are compared with the `.equals(String str)` method.

```
 if(elements[i][x].Xpos()==2 && elements[i][x].Ypos()==2){
                        elements[i][x].setIcon(Image);
                        cSquare[i][x].setChessPiece("Image");
```

If statements do not end with a semi colon (`;`).

Fix those and see how it goes.

Comment: @npinti... Npinti...it still doesn't let me perform the action on multiple elements, it only works on one. how do i get all pieces to move around on the board?

Comment: @npinti... don't worry, i've sorted it.

Comment: @user3458412: Can you specify on what the issue was?